# Can my mage prepare powers of the same level but of a different type (encounter, daily, utility)?

Tags: spells, dnd-4e

I'm reading about the Mage on the *Heroes of the Fallen Lands*, and page 200 says

> You cannot prepare more than one power of any given level on the same day. For example, a 14th level mage [...] can prepare three encounter attack powers per day. Her spellbook contains multiple encounter attack powers at various levels. She can prepare three powers from any of the levels, as long as none of the prepared powers are of the same level

The starting sentence implies that all powers, e.g. 3 encounter, 3 daily, 3 utility for a 14th level character have to be from different levels. This means, 9 powers all of different levels. The example goes into more detail and implies somehow that I could choose, say, 1 level 14 encounter power, 1 level 14 daily, 1 level 14 utility, or 3 of one level, 3 of another, 3 of a third different level. Which is correct?

**EDIT** To be clear, I'm speaking about preparing spells for the day, after having taken an extended rest. Let's assume I already have learned any spells I want to prepare.

**EDIT 2** I understand now that this is kind of silly. If you couldn't prepare, say, a Daily 1 and an Encounter 1 Power, at level 1 you'd be stuck with just one power, either Daily or Encounter, because they both must be Level 1.

**EDIT 3** Recent errata clarifies this. Quoting from http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/updates:

> Mage’s Spellbook [page] 200 Second
>   paragraph, first three sentences
>   replaced with “Find your level on the
>   Spells Prepared per Day table. The row
>   corresponding to your level indicates
>   how many encounter attack powers,
>   daily attack powers, and utility
>   powers you are allowed to prepare each
>   day. You cannot prepare more than one
>   encounter attack power, daily attack
>   power, or utility power of any given
>   level on the same day.” This change
>   makes clear that the mage is permitted
>   to prepare both an encounter attack
>   power and a daily attack power at
>   first level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must only prepare spells that are different levels within a power type (Encounter, Daily or Utility).  Example: You have a spellbook that lists 2 - 14th level spells as available to your character to prepare. In preparing spells for the day you can only prepare one of them, period.

You would not necessarily have different levels between power types.  Example: You might a have a 1st level Encounter and a 1st level Daily prepared.  You would not have 2 1st level Daily's prepared.

Added per Request From comments below:

Yes. DDI: "Spells Prepared per Day" table shows how many encounter, daily, and utility powers you are allowed to prepare each day. You cannot prepare more than one power of any given level on the same day. For example, a 14th-level mage who has taken the enigmatic mage paragon path can prepare four encounter attack powers per day. Her spellbook contains multiple encounter attack powers at various levels. She can prepare four powers from any of the levels, as long as none of the prepared powers are of the same level. Treat each power type (E.D.U.) separately.

Your example: "Her spellbook contains multiple **ENCOUNTER** attack powers at various levels. She can prepare..." is the key to the answer.

Comment: Is this written somewhere?

Comment: Yes. DDI: "Spells Prepared per Day" table shows how many encounter, daily, and utility powers you are allowed to prepare each day. You cannot prepare more than one power of any given level on the same day. For example, a 14th-level mage who has taken the enigmatic mage paragon path can prepare four encounter attack powers per day. Her spellbook contains multiple encounter attack powers at various levels. She can prepare four powers from any of the levels, as long as none of the prepared powers are of the same level.  Treat each power type (E.D.U.) separately.

Comment: Your example: "Her spellbook contains multiple ENCOUNTER attack powers at various levels. She can prepare..." is the key to the answer.

Comment: Could you add your comment to the answer?

Comment: Added per request.

Answer (score 2):

You have different *slots* available for your prep. A level 5 character will have a level 5 daily and a level 1 daily available, each with their own option set. You may, however, learn a level 1 daily *as* your level 5 daily.

From [DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/class.aspx?id=722):

> MAGE'S SPELLBOOK
>   At the end of each of your extended rests, you can prepare encounter attack powers, daily attack powers, and utility powers from your spellbook. These are the powers that you can use during that day, in addition to your at-will attack powers, cantrips, and nonwizard powers, such as a racial power. If you do not prepare powers from your spellbook after an extended rest (for example, if you do not have access to your spellbook), you can use the same powers you had prepared on the previous day.
>
> Find your level on the Spells Prepared per Day table. The row corresponding to your level indicates how many encounter attack powers, daily attack powers, and utility powers you are allowed to prepare each day. You cannot prepare more than one power of any given level on the same day. For example, a 14th-level mage who has taken the enigmatic mage paragon path can prepare four encounter attack powers per day. Her spellbook contains multiple encounter attack powers at various levels. She can prepare four powers from any of the levels, as long as none of the prepared powers are of the same level.

```
SPELLS PREPARED PER DAY
Level   Encounter   Daily   Utility
1       1           1       —
2       1           1       1
3-4   2           1       1 
5       2           2       1
6       2           2       2
7-8   3           2       2
9       3           3       2
10-15   3           3       3
16-21   3           3       4
22-30   3           3       5
```

To answer your comments, you must read both sentences: "The row corresponding to your level indicates how many encounter attack powers, daily attack powers, and utility powers you are allowed to prepare each day. You cannot prepare more than one power of any given level on the same day." For each power in set (encounter, daily, utility), prepare power such that there are no equal level powers of equivalent type. Only one level 7 encounter power is possible to prepare at level 7, despite having 3 encounter slots.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, which is not about learning spells but about preparing them for the day after an extended rest: can I prepare a level 5 daily _and_ a level 5 encounter power, or must every power prepared be of a different level?

Comment: There's no such thing as a level 5 encounter power. You may learn 2 spells whenever you gain a new encounter or daily spell. These spells may be of any level up to yours of the appropriate type. Thus, when you ding 5, you may learn a level 1 flaming sphere and a level 5 fireball. As part of your level 5 daily, you fill that slot with *either* flaming sphere or fireball. When you hit level 7, you'll be casting 1 of 2 spells from your level 1 (both level 1) encounter, 1 of 2 spells from your level 3 encounter (level 1 or level 3 encounters possible) and 1 of 2 spells from your level 7.

Comment: Hey, it's the book that says "You cannot prepare more than one power of any given level", not me. I did say I was reading `HotFL`, where at level 5 you get two of three "Wizard Attack 5" powers. I'm sorry, but if your answer is answering my question, I don't understand how.

Comment: Re: your edit. Yes, I know that. "For each power in set (encounter, daily, utility), prepare power such that there are no equal level powers of equivalent type." is what I was asking.

Answer (score 1):

> You cannot prepare more than one power of any given level on the same day

Seems to me to be pretty set in stone.

Given that the rules as written, deny the Mage the ability to prepare both level 1 daily and level 1 at will powers, which is clearly not the intent here, the rules can be assumed to be wrong.

The only guidance that I am aware of on how to resolve this, would appear to be the Wizard spellbook class feature:

> After an extended rest, you can prepare a number of daily and utility spells according to what you can cast per day for your level. You can’t prepare the same spell twice.

The use of "what you can cast per day for your level" and the normal power selection rules which allow you to take powers of lower levels of the correct type in place of powers of the level at which the power is granted, permits you to prepare, say, ***Sleep*** as your level 1 daily, and then ***Horrid Whispers*** (another level 1 daily) in your level 5 daily slot.